# When Page reloads, controls which were loaded newly are not accessible from javascript

Tags: javascript

In my usecase, post click of certain button, one Unordered list gets loaded(which was not there initially.)
Now when I try to get the UL(with getElementByClassName()), It is not getting returned.

When I inspect UL with the help of developer tool, and I try getElementByClassName(), I am able to find the control(with same piece of script) . Do I need to refresh or something?

Before click of button:

```
<iframe id='ifcontainer'>
    <frameset name="framset1">
    <frameset name="frameset2">
    <frame name="framecontent">
        <!-- this Ul tag loads in html document after click of some button-->
        <ul>

          <li class ="li-selected"> school</li>
        </ul>
```

Script I use is.

```
var iframe=document.getElementById("ifcontainer")
var y=(iframe.contentWindow||y.contentDocument)
var doc=y.document;
doc.getElementsByClassName("li-selected")
```

Comment: It would be much more easier to find out what's going wrong if you would post some code snippets for us.

Comment: sounds like you order a pizza and try to eat it right away. You are not waiting it for it to be ready.

Comment: @epascarello, right now I am trying from console of browser, I waited enough time before executing the script.

Comment: @KarthigaSampath - Try using the statement `doc.getElementsByClassName("li-selected")` in the button click callback function once you add the `ul`.

Comment: @randomSoul Actually I m trying to automate a page, I can't add any contents to the page :(

Comment: @KarthigaSampath - Okay. You can use observer for changes in your `iframe`.

Comment: @randomSoul sure will do

Comment: Below code worked for me.

Comment: var iframe=document.getElementById("ifcontainer")
var y=(iframe.contentWindow||y.contentDocument)
var doc=y.document;
var frames= doc.getElementsByTagName('frame')
var innerDoc=frames[0].contentWindow|frames.contentDocument
doinnerDoc.document.getElementsByClassName("li-selected")

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the iFrame is not from the same origin:
[click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Script_security).

You can't access elements in the iFrame. Where do you get the iFrame from?

Please let us know the code so we can check what's going on.